# Assign Website Id without calling save();

Tags: adminhtml, product-attribute, magento-1, websites, save

I am doing a custom function for magento Admin.
The function is when author finished setup a product and save, the product will automatically assigned to certain `websiteId` when the conditions is met.

For that purposes I use `catalog_product_save_after` event. In that event, i cannot call `->save()` otherwise its gonna be infinite loop.

I tried

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(13,14,1,7));
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'website_ids');
```

But it seems that `saveAttribute` doesnt work on array attribute.

How should i assign desired `websiteId` to the product?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you should use the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Website` class.

This class is used when you update the websites for product action in the backend.

You can use it by doing the following to add products to websites:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts($websiteIds, $productIds);
```

To remove products from websites you can do:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->removeProducts($websiteIds, $productIds);
```

You won't face any issue with the `save` method as those methods are using a resource model to interact directly with the database, for example the `addProducts` method looks like this:

```
public function addProducts($websiteIds, $productIds)
{
    if (!is_array($websiteIds) || !is_array($productIds)
        || count($websiteIds) == 0 || count($productIds) == 0)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->beginTransaction();

    // Before adding of products we should remove it old rows with same ids
    $this->removeProducts($websiteIds, $productIds);
    try {
        foreach ($websiteIds as $websiteId) {
            foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
                if (!$productId) {
                    continue;
                }
                $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insert($this->getMainTable(), array(
                    'product_id' => (int) $productId,
                    'website_id' => (int) $websiteId
                ));
            }

            // Refresh product enabled index
            $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($websiteId)->getStoreIds();
            foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
                $this->_getProductResource()->refreshEnabledIndex($store, $productIds);
            }
        }

        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
    return $this;
}
```